# Angular How can i use that Json Data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i have to use the data coming from that service:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=london

All the data is mixed with html, after cleaning it with that online [tools](http://codebeautify.org/jsviewer)

Here's the data:

```
cb({
        "title": "Recent Uploads tagged london",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/london/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2015-06-27T17:21:27Z",
        "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "items": [
       {
            "title": "Citywards",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/peterphotographic/19182673346/",
            "media": {"m":"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/269/19182673346_eae48f0d5d_m.jpg"},
            "date_taken": "2015-06-22T20:25:21-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/peterphotographic/\">peterphotographic<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/peterphotographic/19182673346/\" title=\"Citywards\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/269/19182673346_eae48f0d5d_m.jpg\" width=\"173\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Citywards\" /><\/a><\/p> <p>W&amp;DPS City Walk 2015<br /> <br /> Thameside, London, UK<\/p>",
...ETC
```

What should I do to clean and display for example each item in a ng-repeat?

here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCb8hgQuaL1z5X63WIaE?p=preview)

**For somes who can't see anything it is probably because you are getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue, you can install this chrome plugin, activate it and refresh the page you will see the data and the log:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

I met the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For somes who can't see anything it is probably because you are
>   getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue, you can install this
>   chrome plugin, activate it and refresh the page you will see the data
>   and the log:
>
> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

The bad way to do it, cause you can't ask your users to allow Cross Origin Calls, since you make them vulnerable to attacks. Relevant OWASP wikis -> [CORS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing), [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

The response is you are getting is [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). For cross domain request we should use JSONP.

You should change `&jsoncallback=cb` to `&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK` because AngularJS [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method wants it to be that otherwise the `.success` wont fire.

Another thing from your code, `method: 'POST'` is used to send data to server and not to get data. So to get data from server we should use HTTP GET method.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = null;
  $http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK&tags=london')
    .success(function(res) {
      console.log(res.items);
      $scope.data = res.items;
    })
    .error(function() {
      //handle error
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <hr />
   <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      <div>
        <p>Title: {{item.title}}</p>
        <p>Author: {{item.author}}</p>
        <img ng-src="{{item.media.m}}" />
        <p>Tags: {{item.tags}} </p>
        <p>Published at: {{item.published}}</p>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K8JtNnf2nAioOUrCfuDm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Flickr uses JSONP, as you have to provide the callback function name. Therefore I think that the URL you are calling should look like following:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK&tags=london (notice the changed value of the *jsoncallback* param). And you should use the JSONP method of HTTP to make the call:

```
return $http.jsonp('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK&tags=london');
```

and then in the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, getFlickrImages) {
$scope.data = null;
     getFlickrImages.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
       $scope.data = dataResponse;     
   });

});
```

`$scope.data` should hold the payload of the call as JS object. If it passed as string, you can easily parse it to JS object with `angular.fromJSon()` function.

Then in the UI you can do the following:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
      <div>
       <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I haven't tested the code, so it's provided as-is.